# Drawing a line that follows two independent objects

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I'm trying to draw a line on the screen that follows two moving objects. Meaning that each end is connected to one of the objects, even though the objects move independently from one another. Here is my code for drawing my line:

```
CCDrawNode *draw = [[CCDrawNode alloc] init];
CCColor *color = [[CCColor alloc]initWithCcColor3b:ccc3(140, 100, 10)];


CGPoint worldCoordCart = [_cart convertToWorldSpace: _cart.position];
CGPoint worldCoordClaw = [_claw convertToWorldSpace: _claw.position];


[draw drawSegmentFrom:worldCoordCart to:worldCoordClaw radius:5 color: color];


[self addChild:draw];
```

How would I go about trying to update the draw method in a sense so that the line is always connected to both objects? And how come my line segment ain't between my objects even though it seems to me that their positions should be the same? I feel like I'm missing something fundamental when it comes to the understanding of world space positioning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`_cart.position` is its position in its parent, not in _cart. Try

```
CGPoint worldCoordCart = [_cart.parent convertToWorldSpace:_cart.position];
```

Same for _claw.

Also, I dont think a draw primitive embedded in a CCDrawNode can be updated. I think you will have to subclass CCDrawNode and provide yourself with methods to update the start and end locations. When either is updated, you start by using the `clear` method, and then simply add a new line segment with the updated coordinates.

Comment: Thanks, it fixed my line position in the case of my cart, but my position for the claw is still messed up. Might be because the claw is constantly rotating? 

What kind of update method do you suggest to use? CCActionRepeat or more in the line of  a schedule method?

Comment: Wait, I think I misunderstood your answer at first. Do you mean that I should draw the line segment with the correct position at that time, then when the positions changes clear the line and draw a completely knew one? And wouldn't that be possible without subclassing and making my own methods? (Sorry, I'm still fresh to Cocos2d and Objective-C)

Comment: Yes, you could do this without subclassing in update, but you will need to have an iVar for the `CCDrawNode` so you can refer to it in update. And yes, rotation and scaling can play with your mind when it comes to position. Subclassing could allow you to encapsulate the complexity of this draw in one convenient place without cluttering `self``'s class code. gluck.